# How to evaluate gcc format-overflow checking size 72

Tags: c, gcc

My sample code (t.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
        /* 12345678901234567890
         * 2017/09/06 12:28:30  */
        char wtime[19];
        time_t t=time(NULL);
        struct tm *pt = localtime(&t);
        sprintf(wtime, "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", pt->tm_year+1900,
            pt->tm_mon+1, pt->tm_mday, pt->tm_hour, pt->tm_min, pt->tm_sec);
        printf("%s %ld\n", wtime, sizeof(int));
        return 0;
}
```

Warning message by `gcc -Wall -Wformat=2 -m64 t.c` (gcc 7.1.1)

```
t.c:9:47: warning: ‘sprintf’ writing a terminating nul past the end of the destination [-Wformat-overflow=]
  sprintf(wtime, "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", pt->tm_year+1900,
                                               ^
t.c:9:2: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 20 and 72 bytes into a destination of size 19
  sprintf(wtime, "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", pt->tm_year+1900,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pt->tm_mon+1, pt->tm_mday, pt->tm_hour, pt->tm_min, pt->tm_sec);
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The number 20 in the message is 19 and one terminator ('\0').
I am wonder, why there is a number 72? How to evaluate it.  It is not necessary to increase wtime as size 72 in this sample.

Comment: I recommend to always use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) so code instead `snprintf(wtim, sizeof(wtim), "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d"` ... `)`

Comment: And in your case better use [strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `"%d"` format is for `int`, which is usually a 32-bit signed integer type. That means it can have up to 11 characters when printed (10 digits plus a possible minus for negative numbers). You have six of those meaning that's up to 66 character.

Then you have five other characters (two each of `'/'` and `':'`, and a space).

Plus terminator.

That's 72.

And remember that the `"04"` part of `"%04d"` means it will print four digits left-padded with zeros, but if there's more digits then it will print all of them. It's not an absolute limit.

Therefore at least 20 characters, but up to 72.

Comment: What to do against it?

Comment: @TJJ Increase the buffer size to be big enough to fit all character, including the terminator. Or use `snprintf` to not overwrite the buffer.

Comment: I know from what I feed into sprintf that `%02d` cannot be bigger than two digits. But the warning also occurs with `snprintf`. I don't want to make the buffer bigger, because I want to save every bit of RAM possible. Is there a solution to get rid of the warning? Maybe even to ignore it?

Comment: @TJJ [Incorrect](https://ideone.com/PwTD0o). For integers the precision is minimum justification, not max number of digits to show.

Comment: No, not in my case. That's why I specified "from what I feed into `sprintf`". I do `iNum = iNum % 100` beforehand. Should have clarified that my int-variable cannot be bigger than 2 digits. Also, the numbers are always positive. So it's max. 2 digits, but I still get the warning. I think to get rid of the warning I need to check the return-value of `snprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

Every string in C must have a null terminator, in order to know where the string ends, but I guess you already know that from your reputation.

The error message says the string can have any number between 20 and 72 bytes, that is between 19 and 71 characters plus the null terminator.

19 characters is found by finding the minimum possible string, which contains 19 characters because of the leading zeroes at each value. This formatted string can also contain up to 71 characters because of the limits of `int` (a number that can go up to 10 digits), so summing 11 in each `%d` occurrence (worst-case scenario with a leading negative sign) plus the other characters gives us 71).

By having only 19 bytes to store the string, it is impossible to fit it all plus the null terminator, hence the error. So if you increase the size of your char array to 20 it is possible that it works because it is within the limits, but it is not guaranteed since the numbers can exceed this size.