# Error with sprintf(): ‘__builtin___sprintf_chk’ may write a terminating nul past the end of the destination

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a toolchain for RX following [this guide](http://thwebel.de/?p=96). The guide is using the following tools:

```
GCC-4.6.4
binutils-2.23.52
gdb-7.6
newlib-2.0.0
```

When I run the very first `make`, I face this error:

> ../../binutils-2.23.52/binutils/prdbg.c:500:20: error: ‘__builtin___sprintf_chk’ may write a terminating nul past the end of the destination [-Werror=format-overflow=]
>   sprintf (buf, "%ld", (long) vma);

Then I open the code and navigate to this part, which is supposed to have an error:

```
static void
print_vma (bfd_vma vma, char *buf, bfd_boolean unsignedp, bfd_boolean hexp)
{
  if (sizeof (vma) <= sizeof (unsigned long))
    {
      if (hexp)
    sprintf (buf, "0x%lx", (unsigned long) vma);
      else if (unsignedp)
    sprintf (buf, "%lu", (unsigned long) vma);
      else
    sprintf (buf, "%ld", (long) vma); // <-- this line
    }
    // ... // some code below
```

I searched and found these question: [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697753/how-to-suppress-sprintf-warning-directive-writing-between-1-and-11-bytes-into) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066859/how-to-evaluate-gcc-format-overflow-checking-size-72). I understand that this overflow error is because the buffer is not large enough to contain all the data. But [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) states that both `long` and `unsigned long` have the same storage sizes (8 bytes).

I tried replacing `long` with `unsigned long` and it passed, no more errors on this file (so I think there is no relevant error with the code below) but I don't think this is a good way to do.

So, I really don't understand why `long` causes error while `unsigned long` doesn't. Or do I misunderstand something ? Thank you for your help.

---

ps: actually before this error, I faced these 2 errors (in other files) first:

- fall through
- negative shifting

But they're not relevant to this error (and I fixed them) so I skipped.

Comment: The size of *long* is not relevant, it is the size of the generated string that matters.  Since *long* can be a 64-bit type, you'd need space for at least 19 digits, one more for the sign if it is a signed long, one more for the zero-terminator.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, I understand it. But I sees that for 64-bit (unsigned or not) long, it needs at most 20 bytes to display. And for 32-bit (unsinged or not) long, it needs at most 10 bytes. So I'm still stuck.

Comment: @Tiendung 21, not 20; if you take into account the null terminator.

Comment: @Acorn thank you, I didn't know about the null terminator, that's what the error is trying to tell me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry for the 32-bit part in my first comment. You did mention zero-terminator too. I assume it's another way to call null terminator ? Coming from python, this is really new to me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **storage size** of an unsigned long may be 8 bytes, but the **decimal representation** in a string may be longer!

For example, `2^32` fits in 4 byte, but the string representation `"4294967296"` needs 11 bytes (mind the implicit zero byte as string terminator)! So you need to provide a bigger buffer than 8 bytes for your `sprintf()` target.

Generally spoken, you need `ceil(log_10(max_value_of_datatype)) + 1 (zero byte)` bytes for the decimal string representation (and maybe an extra byte for the minus sign, depending on the signedness).

For a 64-bit unsigned value, this results in
`ceil(log_10(2^64)) + 1 = 21 bytes`

Same result for 64-bit signed: `ceil(log_10(2^63)) + 1 + 1 (for minus sign) = 21 bytes`.

For a 32-bit unsigned value, this results in `ceil(log_10(2^32)) + 1) = 11 bytes`, and for 32-bit signed values, the necessary space is `ceil(log_10(2^31)) + 2) = 12 bytes`!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the null terminator, then the difference may be in the 32-bit unsigned long (11 bytes) vs signed long (12 bytes). Please also add this to your answer for clarification.